# How do I extract only the result from the following JSON array?

Tags: java, json

I have the JSON array in the following format obtained from an API:

```
[{"confidence": "71.5579", "result": "Positive"}, 
{"confidence": "78.8726", "result": "Negative"}, 
{"confidence": "50.0000", "result": "Neutral"}, 
{"confidence": "57.7676", "result": "Neutral"}]
```

How do I get only the result part i.e. "Positive", "Negative" and so on into a string array? Or just get the count of positive, negative and neutral? Do I need to use any external jars for it? Working in eclipse here.

Comment: You may use a JSON library such as JsonSimple or GSON to parse the code into a JSON object and then get values as you please. Read the documentation of the library you use to see how parsing, and value manipulation is done.
Lastly, you can also get the results by performing basic String operations and String editing but i dont really recomend it, it defeats the purpose of JSON.

Comment: @fillpant Thanks, I used JSON library to make it work and yes, using basic string matching was what I thought of initially but this definitely beats basic string matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of project you are working on, but if yo have access to the org.json package. Their is org.json.JSONObject and org.json.JSONArray classes which you can parse as thus

```
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("<string result from API>");
        int lenght = jsonArray.length();
        String[] results = new String[lenght];
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            results[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("result");
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have any built-in support for reading JSON so yes, you will need to use a library. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) is a popular choice, you can see some examples of how it is used [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/).